# How can I direct from main page menu to second main page with frameset?

Tags: html, css, href, frame

I have a main page with no frameset, this main page has its own menu. 
Then I have a second "main" page that its divided in 4 frames (top, left, middle and right) the left frame has the same menu as the main page, and the content its targeted to the middle frame. 
Now my question is How can I make that from the main page menu it send you to the second main page with the frame sets but with another page in the middle and so on for all the topics.
I'm a highschool student doing my final project.

Comment: Write what you have done by now.

Comment: Some of your code will help to undestand what you are trying to achieve.
Did you realize that **_The <frameset> tag is not supported in HTML5_**.
[Check this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp)
If you mean to scroll to another content use id's and link to them:

Comment: Unless you are working on a legacy project, do not use `<frameset>`. It is outdated, it is not supported in HTML5, it is incompatible with responsive design, and it is even bad for SEO.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely HAVE to use HTML4.01, you can use this technique with a little bit of "onclick" javascript.
Repeat the technique for further frames.
index.html:

```
     <html>

     <frameset rows="50%,50%">
      <frame src="frame_a.htm">
      <frameset cols="30%,30%,30%">
       <frame src="frame_b.htm">
      <frame id= "framec" >
      <frame src="frame_d.htm">
    </frameset>
   </frameset>
   </html>
```

frame_b.htm:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="english" value="English" onClick="window.parent.document.getElementById('framec').src='english.html';" > 
</body>
</html>
```

english.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>    This is the english Page</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a query string in your url from your first main page like:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="secondpage.html?content=home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="secondpage.html?content=about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="secondpage.html?content=contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then for your second main page get the query string parameters with javascript and load the frame accordingly:

```
<iframe id="frame-content"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var content_to_load = getParameterByName("content");

    if (content_to_load == "home") {
        document.getElementById('frame-content').src = "home.html";
    } else if (content_to_load == "about") {
        document.getElementById('frame-content').src = "about.html";
    } else if (content_to_load == "contact") {
        document.getElementById('frame-content').src = "contact.html";
    }

    function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return results[2].replace(/\+/g, " ");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try something like that:

**In your main page (without frameset):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Main Page Without Frameset</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Main Page Without Frameset</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html?target=google" target="main">Google</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html?target=yahoo" target="main">Yahoo</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html?target=coursera" target="main">Coursera</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**In your frameset**

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {

        var location = window.location.href;

        var target = getParameterByName('target', location) !== null ? getParameterByName('target', location)+'.html' : 'middle.html';

        document.getElementById("main").setAttribute("src", target);

        console.log('target: ', target);

        function getParameterByName(_name, _url) {
            var [name, url] = [_name, _url];
            if (!url) url = window.location.href;
            name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
            var regex = new RegExp(`[?&]${name}(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)`);
            var results = regex.exec(url);
            if (!results) return null;
            if (!results[2]) return '';
            return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        };
    }
</script>
<frameset rows="25%,*">
  <frame src="top.html">
  <frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
      <frame src="left.html" name="left">
      <frame src="middle.html" name="main" id="main">
      <frame src="right.html" name="right">
  </frameset>
</frameset>
```

**Finally, your left.html is that...**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>left</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background: #ff0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Left</h1>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="google.html" target="main">Google</a></li>
        <li><a href="yahoo.html" target="main">Yahoo</a></li>
        <li><a href="coursera.html" target="main">Coursera</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**What are we doing herer?**

First we pass a reference for what page we can open in the main frame. After, we use a helper function to capture this reference from the url. Then, we parse this reference as a html file name string, and pass it to our "src" frame attribute. That's all.